# Using react, how would I hide a table row on click?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, hide

Hey guys I am using this table to display data and I added a button to each row. How would I be able to hide a row when I click the hide button next to it?

I am aware of a way to do within html elements but not sure how to hide a particular row within a table thats within a loop

Can anyone show me how to accomplish this?

Thank you

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class Table extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props) //since we are extending class Table so we have to use super in order to override Component class constructor
      this.state = { //state is by default an object
         students: [
            { id: 1, name: 'Wasif', age: 21, email: 'wasif@email.com' },
            { id: 2, name: 'Ali', age: 19, email: 'ali@email.com' },
            { id: 3, name: 'Saad', age: 16, email: 'saad@email.com' },
            { id: 4, name: 'Asad', age: 25, email: 'asad@email.com' }
         ]
      }
   }

   renderTableData() {
    return this.state.students.map((student, index) => {
       const { id, name, age, email } = student //destructuring
       return (
          <tr key={id}>
             <td>{id}</td>
             <td>{name}</td>
             <td>{age}</td>
             <td>{email}</td>
             <td><button>HIDE</button></td>
          </tr>
       )
    })



 }
renderTableHeader() {
      let header = Object.keys(this.state.students[0])
      return header.map((key, index) => {
         return <th key={index}>{key.toUpperCase()}</th>
      })
   }







   render() { //Whenever our class runs, render method will be called automatically, it may have already defined in the constructor behind the scene.
    return (
      <div>
         <h1 id='title'>React Dynamic Table</h1>
         <table id='students'>
            <tbody>
               <tr>{this.renderTableHeader()}</tr>
               {this.renderTableData()}
            </tbody>
         </table>
      </div>
   )
}
}

export default Table
```

Comment: I used `className` attribute with with a class having `display: 'none'`, we can also use inline `style` attribute on tr ( HTML ) / TableRow ( MUI ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add an `onClick` handler to the `button` that adds a property that determines the `student` should be hidden or not.

Notice the `onClick={() => this.hideRow(id)}` below.

```js
renderTableData() {
  return this.state.students.map((student, index) => {
    const { id, name, age, email, isHidden } = student; //destructuring

    // isHidden will default to undefined if not found on the student object
    
    // user is hidden
    if (isHidden === true) {
      return null;
    }

    return (
      <tr key={id}>
        <td>{id}</td>
        <td>{name}</td>
        <td>{age}</td>
        <td>{email}</td>
        <td>
          <button onClick={() => this.hideRow(id)}>HIDE</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    );
  });
}
```

The `hideRow` method will accept a student `id` and will add an `isHidden: true` attribute to the student with that `id`.

```js
hideRow(id) {
  const students = this.state.students.map((student) => {
    // not same id? leave as is
    if (student.id !== id) {
      return student;
    }

    return { ...student, isHidden: true };
  });

  this.setState({ students });
}
```

Now you don't want to display the `isHidden` column, so you have to update `renderTableHeader` method to skip that.

```js
renderTableHeader() {
  let header = Object.keys(this.state.students[0]);
  return header.map((key, index) => {
   
    // notice this
    if (key === "isHidden") {
      return null;
    }

    return <th key={index}>{key.toUpperCase()}</th>;
  });
}
```

[image: Edit musing-cherry-y7i5c]

Answer (score 1):

Add a isVisible key in all objects like

```
 students: [
            { id: 1, name: 'Wasif', age: 21, email: 'wasif@email.com', isVisible: true },
            { id: 2, name: 'Ali', age: 19, email: 'ali@email.com', isVisible: true },
            { id: 3, name: 'Saad', age: 16, email: 'saad@email.com', isVisible: true },
            { id: 4, name: 'Asad', age: 25, email: 'asad@email.com', isVisible: true }
         ]
```

Then in your render row function do this

```
renderTableData() {
    return this.state.students.map((student, index) => {
       const { id, name, age, email, isVisible } = student
       return isVisible ? (
          <tr key={id}>
             <td>{id}</td>
             <td>{name}</td>
             <td>{age}</td>
             <td>{email}</td>
             <td><button>HIDE</button></td>
          </tr>
       ) : null
    })
```

On button/row click update state.

Comment: on click I would find a way to update the isvisible field to false?

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this code

import React, { Component } from "react";

class Table extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props); //since we are extending class Table so we have to use super in order to override Component class constructor
    this.state = {
      //state is by default an object
      students: [
        { id: 1, name: "Wasif", age: 21, email: "wasif@email.com", toggle: true},
        { id: 2, name: "Ali", age: 19, email: "ali@email.com", toggle: true },
        { id: 3, name: "Saad", age: 16, email: "saad@email.com", toggle: true},
        { id: 4, name: "Asad", age: 25, email: "asad@email.com", toggle: true }
      ]
    };
  }
  handleClick(index) {
    let students = [...this.state.students];
    students[index].toggle = !students[index].toggle;
    this.setState({ students });
  }
  renderTableData() {
    return this.state.students.map((student, index) => {
      const { id, name, age, email, toggle } = student; //destructuring
      if (toggle) {
        return (
          <tr key={id}>
            <td>{id}</td>
            <td>{name}</td>
            <td>{age}</td>
            <td>{email}</td>
            <`td`>
              <button
                value={index}
                onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(e.target.value)}
              >
                Hide
              </button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        );
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    });
  }
  renderTableHeader() {
    let header = Object.keys(this.state.students[0]);
    return header.map((key, index) => {
      return <th key={index}>{key.toUpperCase()}</th>;
    });
  }

  render() {
    //Whenever our class runs, render method will be called automatically, it may have already defined in the constructor behind the scene.
    return (
      <div>
        <h1 id="title">React Dynamic Table</h1>
        <table id="students">
          <tbody>
            <tr>{this.renderTableHeader()}</tr>
            {this.renderTableData()}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Table;
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps:

1. Put an onclick on the button
2. Pass the array as props to the component
3. On the next component display the array
4. Add the onclick method to it which is also passed as a props from the main component(Pass id as a parameter)
5. In the method use a filter array to remove the row of your choice when you click it.
   The code is as follow:

https://codesandbox.io/s/modern-tdd-mlmzl?file=/src/components/Table.js

Comment: Hiding and removing are 2 different things.